# How to customise a button with out div and label in WTForms?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

When I'm using `wtforms`, I want to customise a ButtonField.

I read the Docs and i wrote three classes `ButtonFiled()` `ButtonWidget(object)` and `ButtonInput(Input)`.

I almost copy the codes from the packages, but it act not the same as SubmitField. Like the picture below--i can't post a Pic, so i give the url.

My Customise button will always be covered by a div and always a Label shows...

[image]

My Codes：

```
# !/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
'''

'''
from werkzeug.utils import escape
from wtforms import BooleanField,Field
from wtforms.widgets import HTMLString, html_params, Input, SubmitInput
from wtforms.compat import text_type

__author__ = 'Jux.Liu'


class ButtonWidget(object):
    '''
    用于显示按钮(button)的部件(widget)
    '''
    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('name', field.name)
        kwargs.setdefault('value', field.value)
        kwargs.setdefault('type', "submit")
        return HTMLString('<button %s>%s</button>' % (
            html_params(**kwargs),
            escape(field._value())
            ))


class ButtonInput(Input):
    """
    Renders a submit button.

    The field's label is used as the text of the submit button instead of the
    data on the field.
    """
    input_type = 'submit'

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('value', field.label.text)
        return super(ButtonInput, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)


class ButtonOneField(BooleanField):
    '''
    定义可以将按钮(button)用于 Flask 表单(form)的域(field)
    '''
    widget = SubmitInput()


class ButtonTwoField(Field):
    '''
    定义可以将按钮(button)用于 Flask 表单(form)的域(field)
    '''
    widget = ButtonWidget()

    def __init__(self, text, name, value, **kwargs):
        super(ButtonTwoField, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.text = text
        self.value = value
        self.name = name

    def _value(self):
        return str(self.text)
```

Package Codes Segment:

```
class SubmitField(BooleanField):
    """
    Represents an ``<input type="submit">``.  This allows checking if a given
    submit button has been pressed.
    """
    widget = widgets.SubmitInput()

class BooleanField(Field):
    """
    Represents an ``<input type="checkbox">``.

    :param false_values:
        If provided, a sequence of strings each of which is an exact match
        string of what is considered a "false" value. Defaults to the tuple
        ``('false', '')``
    """
    widget = widgets.CheckboxInput()
    false_values = ('false', '')

    def __init__(self, label=None, validators=None, false_values=None, **kwargs):
        super(BooleanField, self).__init__(label, validators, **kwargs)
        if false_values is not None:
            self.false_values = false_values
    def _value(self):
        if self.raw_data:
            return text_type(self.raw_data[0])
        else:
            return 'y'

class SubmitInput(Input):
    """
    Renders a submit button.

    The field's label is used as the text of the submit button instead of the
    data on the field.
    """
    input_type = 'submit'

    def __call__(self, field, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('value', field.label.text)
        return super(SubmitInput, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Can you add your Jinja code?

Comment: i found that it only happends when i use `wtf.quick_form()`, other wise, if I just type the `form.button`, it seems nothing wrong...